# Embedded system update via online platform and serial interface

Tags: web-development, web-server, embedded-systems

I am looking for a software architecture to configure and download a firmware to an embedded system e.g. a STM32 microcontroller.

I want to program an existing .bin file from an online platform to the target hardware. That means e.g. the firmware should be downloaded via serial com port to the embedded controller. Via the online platform I want to load configuration files to the embedded hardware and also via the serial interface.

In the future the whole thing will also be done securely.